# Storing the simulated data set using list() function in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am using the following `r` code to simulate `normal` data set. I have copied them below.

```
set.seed(1234)
ml = matrix(c(4,2,3,5,6,8,1,4,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
ml #left side of parameter
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    1
[2,]    2    6    4
[3,]    3    8    3
mr = matrix(c(6,4,5,2,8,7,6,9,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
mr #right side of parameter
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    2    6
[2,]    4    8    9
[3,]    5    7    4

n = nrow(ml)

set.seed(1234)
y.all = list()
for(j in 1:ncol(ml)){
   for (i in 1:(n - 1)){
      y.all[[i]] = c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
    }
  }

sim.data = matrix(unlist(y.all), ncol(ml)*(ncol(ml) - 1)*ncol(ml), 1, byrow = TRUE)
sim.data = matrix(sim.data, nrow = ncol(ml), ncol = nrow(sim.data)/nrow(ml))
dim(sim.data)
[1] 3 6
sim.data
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6]
[1,] 0.2237461 3.889715 0.2237461 3.889715 0.2237461 3.889715
[2,] 6.0644588 3.488990 6.0644588 3.488990 6.0644588 3.488990
[3,] 6.9594941 8.088805 6.9594941 8.088805 6.9594941 8.088805
```

I used the above code simulate the above `3X6` matrix data set. The first `2 columns` of `sim.data` created using the `1st column` of `ml` and `1st column` of `mr` and so on.

However, I checked them individually in the following way. Unfortunately , they are not same.

```
set.seed(1234)
j = 1
i = 1
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 2.792934 6.277429 7.084441
i = 2
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] -0.3456977  2.4291247  4.5060559
i = 3
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 2.425260 2.453368 2.435548
set.seed(1234)
j = 2
i = 1
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 3.792934 2.277429 3.084441
i = 2
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 3.654302 6.429125 8.506056
i = 3
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 7.425260 7.453368 7.435548
set.seed(1234)
j = 3
i = 1
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] -0.2070657  6.2774292  7.0844412
i = 2
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 1.654302 4.429125 9.506056
i = 3
c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
[1] 2.425260 2.453368 2.435548
```

Am I making any mistake in the above `r` code? Are there any way to simulate the data set?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure of your goal. You want to simulate the same data set in 2 different ways? Why?

Comment: I'm also not sure of what issues I see are intentional and which are bugs. For example, in your upper bit of code, you simulate 6 values in `y.all`, and then replicate them across a 3x6 matrix. Is it intentional or a bug that cols 1,2 are the same as cols 3,4 and cols 5,6 in `sim.data`? In your first `matrix` call, you specify a 1-column matrix, so also specifying `byrow = TRUE` does nothing.

Comment: Overall, I think neither procedure is very clear or efficient. If you are simply mixing normal distributions with different means but all with `var = 1`, I would recommend drawing as many values as you need from a standard normal, and then simply adding the appropriate mean to each observation.

Comment: @Gregor, My code is not working properly. Why the `list()` is overwriting? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Since `y.all` is updated only based on `i` rather than `i` and `j`, when `j` increments the previous `y.all` values are overwritten. That's probably the root of the problem...

Comment: @Gregor, are there any other possible way to avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
y.all = list()
for(j in 1:ncol(ml)){
   for (i in 1:(n - 1)){
      y.all[[i]] = c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
    }
  }
```

Your for loop changes `j` and `i`, but your `y.all` only looks at `i`, so when `j` is changes it overwrites `i`. The simplest fix would be to add a counter:

```
y.all = list()
counter = 1
for(j in 1:ncol(ml)){
   for (i in 1:(n - 1)){
      y.all[[counter]] = c(rnorm(i, ml[i, j], 1), rnorm((n - i), mr[i,j], 1))
      counter = counter + 1
    }
  }
```

This yields results that match your bottom method at first. (They diverge when you use `set.seed()` again in the middle. Perhaps you want the `set.seed` *inside* the outer loop??)

```
         [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6]
[1,] 2.792934 -0.3456977 4.425260 5.109962 0.2237461 3.889715
[2,] 6.277429  2.4291247 1.453368 5.522807 6.0644588 3.488990
[3,] 7.084441  4.5060559 1.435548 7.001614 6.9594941 8.088805
```